# parser for lproj string files

Tags: java, android

I need to read string/translations files from lproj folders ( apple style localisation ) with java. Before writing my own parser I would like to know if I missed an existing one - the style looks like this

```
"string1_key" = "string 1 value";
/** multi line following - and showing comment here **/
"string2_key" = "string 1 
multi line value";
```

at the end I want something like a`HashMap<String,String>` - anyone knows an existing lib for this kind of parsing or do I have to roll my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a parser for this:

https://github.com/ligi/PassAndroid/blob/master/src/main/java/org/ligi/passandroid/model/AppleStylePassTranslation.java